# After an angular function call that shifts the entire document, mouseup is not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular function that changes the state of an ng-if and makes the sidebar show; when the img is clicked, it calls that function, the entire web page is shifted, and at that point the mouseup for the img is no longer triggered when I release the mouse. What can I do to get it to trigger?

Comment: My crystal ball is broken, but my magic 8 ball says, we need some more info. Show the code.

Comment: Use the `mouseleave` event to detect that the cursor is no longer over the  element. Or put a `mouseup` event handler on the `$document` object.

Comment: ah right mouseleave, completely forgot about that. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: @georgeawg been 9+ years that I been using that line here and you are the first to complain. And if the OP would have provided a small snipplet of code, might have gotten some answers in the past hour instead of your one comment with a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@georgeawg provided this answer and it works well enough:

> Use the mouseleave event to detect that the cursor is no longer over the element. Or put a mouseup event handler on the $document object.

Completely forgot about that, so hope that's useful to whoever finds this.